# Mockito any() for a list class

Tags: java, junit4, mockito

Im trying to write a unit test, whereby a call returns a List.. but i cant seem to be able to use :

```
Mockito.any(List.class)
```

how can i do this? any ideas?.. any tutorials

```
Mockito.when(abilityRepository.findRandomAbilitySetForEventLogic(eventLogic, pageableForSingleResult)).thenReturn(abilitySetIds);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc and tutorials show that `any` is a matcher, not something to return. I believe what you want to do is:

```
when(abilityRepository.findRandomAbilitySetForEventLogic(eventLogic, pageableForSingleResult)).thenReturn(ability_ids());

...

private List<AbilitySetId> ability_ids() {
    return new ImmutableList.of(...);
}
```

Of course I made up some names, but that's the idea.